# Touching a capacitive button, non-mechanically

Tags: electricity

This is not about using a capacitive button to control an Arduino; it is the opposite. I would like to "touch" a capacitive button on another conventional device. There could be a way like actually moving a finger-like stick and touch the button, but that is too much work. Can't it be done non-mechanically?

According to this page ( https://scienceline.org/2012/01/okay-but-how-do-touch-screens-actually-work/ ), "Instead, they work with anything that holds an electrical charge – including human skin.". Then, can I emulate "touching" the button by sending some small electrical current?

If so, what module/parts do I need to send such small current?

Comment: It's all about capacitance.  The micro is putting a voltage on that cap sensor and measuring how long it takes to fall or rise.  That gives a measure of capacitance.  When you put your finger you change the capacitance.  Perhaps you could put a second plate there and get the capacitance right to not trigger the button and then have a capacitor that you can switch in to make it higher and trigger it.  Not entirely sure how you'd do that, but maybe it gives you a place to start.

Comment: the button likely handles its own grounding so one question is whether you have access to that device's ground... if not for a purely isolated device, you'd need to mirror their two electrodes.  you then drive a voltage between your two (direction matters for this) to pretend to not touch or connect them to the same (both to either high or low) to simulate a touch

Comment: Check out these links: (1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ji2-2ehLCOQ

(2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ElZec033vQ (3) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSifTiR_e2E (4) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMZrUPBt-7M

Answer (score -1):

The simply way is making a little capacitor.
Cut 2 circle with aluminium from a can and put a paper between them, then solder one one to one circle and other to the other side. One wire goes to the positive and the other to the I/O. When you set to 1 it should create a capacitive charge and "touch" de button.

Comment: "then solder one one..." do you mean "then solder one *wire*..."? Also, "de button" should be "*the* button" and "The simply way" should be "The *simple* way"? The typos aside, your answer would benefit from a diagram as it isn't particularly clear what you mean. "One wire goes to the positive". do you mean Vcc? If so, then what relationship does your DIY capacitor have with the capacitive button on the third-party device? How are they connected? How is the capacitive button activated?